# HTTP_LOG_FIELDS_DATA and Method logging

Tags: logging, http.sys

I'm hitting a snag: the HTTP_LOG_FIELDS_DATA has three fields to specify the Method:

- USHORT MethodLength;
- PCHAR  Method;
- HTTP_VERB MethodNum;

But AFAICT MethodNum is ignored (any value comes up as '-' in the log).

MethodLength & Method work together, but as soon as I set them, f.i. to 3 and 'GET' respectively, I get a 87 error (incorrect parameter) in HttpSendHttpResponse.

The other fields like ClientIpLength/ClientIp or UriStemLength/UriStem work as expected and appear correctly in the log. Method is the problematic one.

Anyone got it working? Any particulars I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it, the bug is in the "HTTP_LOG_FIELDS_DATA structure (Windows)" doc page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364537(v=vs.85).aspx

which is missing a fields in the online doc (both in the C++ code and the description).
I was working from the doc on a Delphi port, then noticed the missing field when testing all fields that were working or not.

After adding the fields, things are back in working order!